# Silverlight RadGridView change TextBox background

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I am facing a small problem using silver light . I have a RadGridView, with four columns. My second columns contains text boxes and the third column contains validation errors. If the third column contains validation errors, i want the second column background to turn red. How can i do this. I have tried binding the text box background column to a string with the desired color but that does not work. Really stuck here. Any help with be much appreciated.

Regards,
Mateen

Comment: If you post example Xaml/Code you are more likely to get detailed/specific answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your binding is otherwise valid, you cannot change colour by binding to a text string of a colour. The background property is of type `Brush`.

You need to either bind to a `Brush` instead, or use a brush/colour converter to return a `Brush` instead of a `Color`/`string` etc.

Try these links for converter examples:

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/20392/70263.aspx

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/20392/70263.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It worked like a charm. I was really puzzled by the behavior. Your a legend.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `StringToObjectConverter` found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/06/09/yet-another-blog-about-ivalueconverter.aspx).  This class has the advantage that it has wider uses that eliminate the need to create a plethora of similar converters.

Further rather than having the bound object have a property called "Background" which tell the UI to "be red".  I would be better that the Model had a property called "Status" which is an enum of the possible states the object is in.

Going further and looking at your specific requirement it would be better that your model exposed a boolean `IsValid` property which a converter could be applied to.  See this [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx) on a generic `BoolToValueConverter`.